# Unicode data retrieved as codes

Tags: python, unicode

I capture the clipboard data which is unicode text. with this code:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
r = Tk()
new_clipboard = r.clipboard_get()
print(new_clipboard)

file = open("jokes.txt", "w")
file.write(json.dumps(new_clipboard)))
file.close()
```

But the result is like this:

```
u'\u0648\u0647\u0627\u060c\u0627\u0646\u06cc\u0645\u06cc\u0634\u0646 \u0647\u0627 \u0648 \u0628\u0633\u06cc\u0627\u0631\u06cc'
```

How can I convert this data to original characters and store them to a file?
Original data format is UTF-8

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: What was the original encoding?

Comment: data encoding is UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Those **are** the original characters.

```
with io.open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
  fp.write(new_clipboard)
```

Comment: how to print as original characters? and what if the new_clipboard is a list of unicodes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **python 2.x** use this code : (in this case if you want to write your Unicode as the original shape you must specify a true encoding for your file ! and use `ensure_ascii=False` in `dump`)

```
#encoding: utf-8 
import io,json

with io.open('jokes.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    json.dump(new_clipboard, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

but in **Python 3.x**, the built-in `open()` is an alias for `io.open()` so if your using **python 3.x** you can use `open()` instead of `io.open()` also note that `new_clipboard` must be Unicode ! i try this and worked well !